# Docusign Envelope Timeout using API

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Rest API V2 that we use a c# Winform application.  We create an envelope with a document in it using the api.  We then redirect user to a win form with a browser control (Internet Explorer).  It worked without issue until late august and we had problems with some users getting logged out after 20-40 seconds while trying to add tags and templates.  It started out with a few users having the issue and seems to be happening more often.

Additional Info.
It doesn't seem to matter on size of document / what you are doing . It happens if you are doing nothing or dragging and tagging etc. It seems to only happen on the preview screen that you can do the drag/tag. This is a sampe of the URL it times out to docusign.com/… –  user3022205 Nov 26 at 18:57

Comment: Lots of variables here that need to be provided: what's in your envelope?  Can you provide details like the documents and their size, the signing instructions etc.  Does the same thing happen if you change some of the variables?  Next thing to check is are a number of users pulling up different sessions in the same browser? Another thing to try is to see if you can just intercept that URL before it goes to control and see what happens when you use a normal browser and different ones.  Let's see what you find out after doing those tests.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter on size of document / what you are doing .  It happens if you are doing nothing or dragging and tagging etc.  It seems to only happen on the preview screen that you can do the drag/tag.  This is a sampe of the URL it times out to  https://www.docusign.com/?event=SessionEnd&envelopeId=dde3a727-9ee6-46ab-95d0-63a3c5848a64